# mySQL field with a dashed line under it.?

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

can anyone please explane what does that dashed line stands for
i am using phpmyadmin

field are

name          type          NULL     default

longtitude      float           No      0.001
latitude    float           No  0.001

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

from http://psych.ucsc.edu/AScils/phpmyadmin/Documentation.html

> $cfg['ShowBrowseComments'] boolean
>   $cfg['ShowPropertyComments'] boolean
>       By setting the corresponding variable to TRUE you can enable the display of column comments in Browse or Property display. In browse mode, the comments are show inside the header. In property mode, comments are displayed using a CSS-formatted dashed-line below the name of the field. The comment is shown as a tool-tip for that field.

So... It looks like the field has a comment attached to it

edit: you can read the comment using:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMS FROM tbl_name LIKE 'col_name';
```

(source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think it means you defined a comment for that field and it is
PhpMyAdmin's polite way to show you can "hover" your mouse over it and
read it.
enjoy